# need help traying to access my database with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, logging

Just built my first database to test out learning skills using the simple query below:

```
<?php

  mysqli_connect("xxx","yyy","zzz" , "newtone" );

if (mysqli_connect_error()){

    echo ("could not connect to database");

    }


?>
```

**This is what I got**

> :(42000/1044): Access denied for user 'yyy'@'xxx' to database 'newtone'......

I don't get it. So When i Use this:

```
mysqli_connect("xxx","yyy","zzz" );

if (mysqli_connect_error()){

    echo ("could not connect to database");

    }


?>
```

I don't get an error message, just a blank page (notice how the database name is not included on the login argument). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not getting the *actual* error. You can find that in your error logs.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your DB login credentials with the entire world. If you post your credit card number(s), social security number, and mother's maiden name, we'll be able to answer your questions right away.

Comment: And don't use a fixed error message. it's useless. `if (mysqli_connect_error()) { die(mysqli_connect_error()); }`. have the DB **TELL** you why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to connect with database then need three things for create connection **dbhost username,dbhost password and your database name**.

```
   <?php
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbuser = "root"; //In case of localhost (default db username)
        $dbpass = ""; //In case of localhost
        $dbname = "testDb";//Your database name

        $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname );

       // Check connection
      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: You are mixing the MySQL and MySQLi Extensions in your answer. Please avoid MySQL and use only MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Yes,I know PHP7 have no more MYSql

Comment: Wonderful :) still, I would prefer the object oriented style, but that's up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd example works because you are successfully connecting to the MySql server, and defaulting to a default database other than "newtone"

If you tried a command like mysqli::select_db after connecting, you would see the same error. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

The crux of your problem seems to be permissions for your user yyy.  Make sure user yyy has various permissions like read/write on the DB "newtone"